# How to get the IP Address in Vagrant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hadoop, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to configure a `Hadoop` cluster, but to do so I needed the ip address of the `namenode`. 
The cluster itself is being created by `Vagrant`, but I don't have the ip address until vagrant creates the instance in AWS.
So, I have the following `Vagrantfile`:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

$master_script = <<SCRIPT
// will write a script to configure 
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    config.vm.box = "dummy"
    aws.access_key_id = "MY_KEY"
    aws.secret_access_key = "SECRET_KEY"
    aws.keypair_name = "my_key"
    aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"
    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "#{current_dir}/my_key.pem"
  end

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      config.vm.box = "precise64"
      config.vm.box_url =  "https://vagrantcloud.com/chef/ubuntu-13.04/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box"
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end

  config.vm.define :namenode do |namenode|
      namenode.vm.box = "dummy"
      namenode.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
         chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
         chef.roles_path = "roles"
         chef.add_role "cluster"
      end
      namenode.vm.provision :hostmanager
      namenode.vm.provision "shell", :inline => $master_script
  end



config.vm.define :slave do |slave|
      slave.vm.box = "dummy"
      slave.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
         chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
         chef.roles_path = "roles"
         chef.add_role "cluster"
      end
      slave.vm.provision :hostmanager
      slave.vm.provision "shell", :inline => $master_script
  end
end
```

I need to update the `mapred-site.xml and core-site.xml` files with the `ip address` of the namenode. How could I get the ip address of the `namenode` box so I can update the hadoop config files? Is there a better option in the cookbook that I can use to accomplish it?
Suppose I have 1 `namenode` and 5 `slaves`, the `mapred-site.xml.erb` template will look like:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>hdfs://<%= node[:ipaddress] %>:8021</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

However, I needed that all the `namenode` and the `slaves` to have the ip address only of the `namenode`. How can I accomplish that in `chef`? 
Either way will work for me, even though I prefer the `chef` solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1- Use the instance metadata service on the namenode instance to find out its own ip:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4
```

see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

2- Tag the namenode (ex: HADOOP_ROLE=NAMENODE) and use AWS CLI on any instance to find the local ip of the namenode:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --region=us-east-1 \
  --filter "Name=tag:HADOOP_ROLE,Values=NAMENODE" \
  --query='Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress' \
  --output=text
```

see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html